# The program '[12460] TestProject.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

I am writing a c# windows form project and when I stop the process this message is shown in the output terminal:

```
The program '[12460] TestProject.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Though the app is running correctly, the -1 exit code seems unfamiliar. Please can anyone explain me what -1 exit code means? Could'nt wrap my head around it.

Comment: Did you stop it by clicking on the `X` at the top right of the window, or by stopping it from Visual Studio?

Comment: @MindSwipe, stopped it from visual studio by clicking on the square icon.

Comment: Stopping a running by clicking "Stop debugging" will force the process to stop and exit with an exit code of -1

Comment: So it is not an issue? Is'nt it the only way to stop debugging? Enlighten me more please

Comment: It's not an issue in the slightest. You're the one who programmed the application, so if you didn't specifically use different exit codes (for example by using `Environment.Exit(some number)`) it should never (in production/ when not being debugged) exit with a non-zero exit code. Instead of clicking it in Visual Studio you could also simply press the `X` on the WinForm. Do also note that force stopping it from Visual Studio will skip certain hooks, like the [application exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the expected behavior. If you click the "Stop" button in Visual Studio, that kills the application immediately and reports the return code as -1 (0xffffffff). If you want to terminate your application normally, click the "X" at the top right corner of the window (if it is a windowed application).

You can also use the "Debug->Detach" menu option to detach the debugger from the application without killing it.